# Is there a key/key lookup table type provided in .NET?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, lookup

It seems like a pretty straightforward thing to add, but I just want to be sure .NET doesn't already provide one and save me from adding unnecessary code:

I need a lookup table (like a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)) that instead using a key/value pair, uses the first key to find the second key, and vice versa. For example -

```
theList.Add("foo", "bar");
x = theList["foo"]; // Returns "bar"
y = theList["bar"]; // Returns "foo"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would this collection do when someone performs: `theList.Add("foo", "bar");` followed by `theList.Add("bar", "baz");` ?

Comment: This is a *bidirectional map*, usually called `BidiMap` or `BiMap` (or, since .NET calls maps dictionaries, in .NET, it would probably be called `BidiDictionary`, `BiDictionary`, or, if you want to be extra clever `Bictionary`). AFAIK, there is no such thing in the BCL, but you might find it in one of the other collections packages, e.g. [C5](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) or [PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com). There are also about 20 questions about this in StackOverflow.

Comment: rwong - I would expect it to throw an exception in that case. Check my answer below -- this is what I was looking to achieve, I just wanted to know if it already had an implementation.

Jörg - Thank you for this! I didn't know the name so I had no idea what to search for. Good to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such datatype, probably because this is a very special requirement which can be easily solved by utilizing a dictionary and adding simply both pairs

```
 theDictionary.Add("foo", "bar");
 theDictionary.Add("bar", "foo");
```

Obviously, you can put this into a generic function like

```
void MyDictAdd(Dictionary<T,T> dict, T key1, T key2)
{
    dict.Add(key1,key2);
    dict.Add(key2,key1);
}
```

Comment: Also, lookups are done with `dict[key]` which you forgot to mention! :)
So if you have a dictionary as such: `var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "somekey", "somevalue" } };` then `dict["somekey"]` will return `"somevalue"`.

Comment: Genius solution. But to implement Count and other functionality, logic is needed

Comment: This solution has one main drawback: key and value have to be the same type.

Comment: @Zoman: that is not a "drawback of this solution", it is what the question necessarily implies. Or, if one needs mixed types, one can still use `object` as common type.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to create a method which would search both keys and values. Also this would and more complexity to the mix O(n) for the search. But would reduce memory usage.

```
string GetValue(string search, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary) {
    foreach(var pair in dictionary)
    {
        if (pair.Key == search) {
            return pair.Value;
        }
        else if (pair.Value == search) {
            return pair.Key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```